# Fast pixel plotting using SWT?

Tags: java, canvas, swt, plot, pixel

I'm looking for a fast and easy way to plot arbitrarily colored pixels in an SWT Canvas.
So far I'm using something like that:

```
// initialization:
GC gc = new GC(canvas);

// inside the drawing loop:
Color cc = new Color(display, r, g, b);
gc.setForeground(cc);
gc.drawPoint(x, y);
cc.dispose();
```

This is horribly horribly slow. it takes about a second and a half to fill a 300x300 canvas with pixels.
I could create an image off-screen, set the pixels in it and then draw the image. This will be faster but I specifically want the gradual painting effect of plotting the image pixel by pixel on the canvas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could draw several offscreen images where you gradually fill the 300x300 area. This way you can control how fast the image should appear.

Comment: This is actually what I ended up doing. filling up scan-line at a time and drawing the scan lines. this method is about 10 times faster. absolutely amazing.

Answer (score 4):

I bet that what is killing performance is allocating and releasing 90,000 `Color` objects.  Remember, in SWT, each `Color` object allocates native resources, which is why you have to `dispose()` it.  This means each time you allocate and dispose a `Color` object, you have to transition from the JVM to native code and back.

Can you cache your `Color` instances while in the 300x300 pixel loop and then dispose of the objects after your loop?  You'd need a somewhat intelligent cache that only holds a maximum of so many objects, and after that will dispose of some of its entries, but this should speed things up **greatly**.

Answer (score -3):

Create a BufferedImage object:

```
BufferedImage bi = new new BufferedImage(300, 300, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
```

inside the drawing loop set your pixels:

```
bi.setRGB(x, y, int_rgb);
...
```

and finally display the buffered image:

```
g.drawImage(bi, 0, 0, null);
```

If you find setRGB() slow, you can access the bitmap data directly:

```
int[] raster = ((DataBufferInt)bi.getRaster().getDataBuffer()).getData();
```

and later

```
raster[y * 300 + x] = int_rgb;
```